# Реализация кнопки "показать еще"

Tags: javascript

Проблема в том, что в мой addEventListener попадают немного не те данные, и я не могу понять в чем дело, хоть и объявил функцию общую. 
Просто кода слишком много и не вижу смысла сюда копировать всё.
Дело в том, что фильрую массив и полученный новый помещаю в функцию titlesOutput. Но так вот получается, что выводится то он нормальный и преобразованный, а эвент на кнопке выводит +15 элементов из списка старого, хотя ссылаюсь я на один и тот же изменённый.

```js
//Показывает список фильмов
function setList(data) {

  let showMore = document.querySelector('.more'),
    filmsList = document.querySelector('.list'),
    movieArray = [],
    moreIndex = 15;

  titlesOutput(data);

  //Вывод первых 15 фильмов
  function titlesOutput(moviesList) {
    movieArray = [];

    //Проверка на количество выводимых фильмов
    //Чтобы не было конфликтов с неизвестными индексами элементов (если фильмов меньше 15)
    if (moviesList.length < 15) {
      moviesList.forEach(object => {
        let li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = object.title;
        filmsList.appendChild(li);
      });
    } else {
      for (let i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
        let li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = moviesList[i].title;
        filmsList.appendChild(li);
      }
    }

    //Занесение в локальный массив полученного после поиска массива из функции ниже.
    movieArray.push(...moviesList);
    console.log(movieArray);
    //Если фильмов в категории меньше 15, то скрыть кнопку "показать еще"
    if (movieArray.length < moreIndex + 15) {
      showMore.style.display = 'none';
    } else {
      showMore.style.display = 'block';
    };

    return movieArray;
  };

  showMore.addEventListener('click', function () {

    // Если невыведенных фильмов осталось меньше чем 15, то вывести оставшиеся и скрыть кнопку.
    if (movieArray.length - moreIndex < 15) {
      for (let i = moreIndex; i < movieArray.length; i++) {
        let li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = movieArray[i].title;
        filmsList.appendChild(li);

        showMore.style.display = 'none';
        //Возвращение индекса в исходное состояние для следующих вызовов.
        moreIndex = 15;
      }
    } else {
      for (let i = moreIndex; i < moreIndex + 15; i++) {
        let li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = movieArray[i].title;
        filmsList.appendChild(li);
      }
      //Прибавление к индексу чтобы выводить следующие 15 фильмов из категории.
      moreIndex += 15;
    };

  });

  //Вывод следущих 15 фильмов ( не знаю как избавиться от повторения кода )
  let searchInput = document.querySelector('.search');

  //Поиск при вводе в input
  searchInput.addEventListener('input', () => {
    let term = searchInput.value;
    filmsList.innerHTML = '';

    //Возвращение индекса в исходное состояние для следующих вызовов.
    moreIndex = 15;

    search(term);
  });

  //Сама вызываемая функция поиска
  function search(term) {
    //Фильтр элементов по значению из input
    let result = data.filter(e => e.title.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1);
    titlesOutput(result);
  }

  //Поиск по тэгам
  let tagList = document.querySelector('.tags'),
    selectedTags = [];

  tagList.addEventListener('click', event => {
    let target = event.target
    filmsList.innerHTML = '';

    //Добавление тэгов в массив при клике на сам тэг
    if (target.tagName == 'A') {
      if (target.classList.contains('selected')) {
        //Удаление тэга из выбранных, если он был уже выбран до этого
        selectedTags.splice(selectedTags.indexOf(target.innerHTML, 0), 1);
        target.classList.remove('selected');
      } else {
        selectedTags.push(target.innerHTML);
        target.classList.add('selected');
      }
    }
    filter(selectedTags);
  });

  //Сам фильтр по тэгам.
  function filter(selectedTags) {
    //Фильтр по выбранным тэгам.
    let result = data.filter(e => selectedTags.every(tag => e.tags.includes(tag)));

    //Возвращение индекса в исходное состояние для следующих вызовов.
    moreIndex = 15;

    titlesOutput(result);
    return result;
  }
}
```

Таков вывод в браузере
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

UPDATE: Если кому интересно, то вот так я это реализовал. Да. 
Правда понял, что утерял логику для сортировки. Мол, надо ведь сортировать выведенный массив и например если я захочу найти фильм с определенным тэгом и чтобы с буквой 'а' - я буду укорачивать свой массив каждый раз безвозвратно.

Comment: `list`, `moviesList`, `itemList` - ничего не понятно

Comment: @Igor забыл удалить просто moviesList. Это неважно. Суть такова, что при клике у меня выводится два массива. Один не фильтрованный, а второй нормальный . Из-за этого я не могу нормально осуществить вывод.

Comment: Я не вижу никакой фильтрации. О чем идет речь? В Вашем коде - один массив.

Comment: `titlesOutput(data);` — по несколько раз вызываете в разных местах? Если да - при каждом вызове вешается новый листенер) В итоге при клике будут работать тупо все.

Comment: @Igor добавил весь код и вывод из браузера. То есть console.log выводит два ответа. Один массив который был до того как что-то с ним сделал и один массив который после изменений (то есть правильный)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME да, с этим нагрешил и решил поделить эти функции. Однако сложно мне как-то пробросить измененный массив внутрь addEventListener. Ну чтобы кнопка всегда реагировала только на последний пришедший туда массив

Comment: Посмотри на значение moreIndex внутри обработчика, он там отличается от ожидаемого showMore.addEventListener('click', function() {. Надо использовать глобальную переменную var.

Comment: Молодец. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вынесите `addEventListener` из `titlesOutput` (и, возможно, из `setList`, если эта функция вызывается больше, чем один раз).
2. На одном уровне с `addEventListener`, заведите переменную, указывающую на массив, чьи элементы Вы хотите выводить в обработчике `click`.
3. `moreIndex` объявите рядом с переменной из пункта 2.

Comment: Если я вынесу addEventListener за пределы setList, то как мне туда добавлять данные из массива ? Ну то есть если я снова создам функцию, которая добавляет addEventListener и закину туда сохраненный в переменной массив - будет же одно и тоже ?

Comment: @4rmr3d1 Смотрите пункт 2.

Comment: Это я понял, просто смысл в том, что на одном уровне с titlesOutput это значит внутри функции setList. Если я заведу там переменную - то она будет локальной внутри setListи если я вынесу addEventListener за пределы setList- то я не смогу к ней обратиться.

Comment: @4rmr3d1 Пардон, поправил пункт 2.

Comment: Передо мной просто встал теперь вопрос о том, как я могу записать всё в массив снаружи этой функции. Ну то есть я знаю про замыкания, но тут задачка будто бы посложнее.

Comment: хотя неважно, я к чему-то пришёл. Спасибо за помощь!